# javascript (especially in angular7) validation without any form (not input,textarea)

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have a material table from excel(Sheet.js),and I need to do valid.

Valid example:
 'col A' only accept number, 
 'col B' only accept number and lower case, 
 'col D' only accept string 'Hello',

Excel table like is : 
[image]

Using 'regular expression' can do that in `<input>` tag, but in material table is `<table>` tag cannot support input pattern valid.

Also, I search for 'JSON Schema' likes ajv.js, most sample is for 'Form',not for date sheet. Is 'JSON Schema' work for me?

Any way to do that in front-end page and can throw error message on screen?

There is my code in Angular:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-excel-pdf

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Do you want to display errors in the uploaded excel sheet in the frontend ? If so you would have to parse the uploaded excel file, check the values and mark the ones that may be invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Finally, I would use JSON Schema tool (likes hapijs/joi) for my values validation. I need to  display errors in the uploaded excel sheet and i actually do parse excel.